# Facebook Dialog Delegate callback value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Trying to implement Facebook iOS SDK on my iphone App. I am using FBDialog Delegate to allow the user to login and get the response/callback using the delegate.

I would like to grab the code in response_type from the user once the login is successful.
Can anyone help me out here or let me know where to take the guide from.

I have the following code which is implemented :

```
-(void) login{
self.fb = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:AppID andDelegate:self];


NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    self.fb.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    self.fb.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

fb.sessionDelegate = self;
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject:AppID forKey:@"client_id"];
[params setObject:@"code" forKey:@"response_type"];

[fb dialog:@"oauth" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

NSLog(@"Callback: %@", params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `didReceiveResponse`, the delegate method called when response is beginning (not yet complete and parsed), get the `statusCode` from the response object.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    if (200 == [response statusCode]) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }    
}
```

Comment: If this answer is correct, you should accept it. This is how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0):

Just handle the delegate methods:

```
/**
 * Your application should implement this delegate to receive session callbacks.
 */
@protocol FBSessionDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

/**
 * Called when the user successfully logged in.
 */
- (void)fbDidLogin;

/**
 * Called when the user dismissed the dialog without logging in.
 */
- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled;

/**
 * Called when the user logged out.
 */
- (void)fbDidLogout;

@end
```

Comment: But I am looking to retrieve specific return data like code and error from facebook session delegate like here : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/ in the return data sections. How can I achieve it ?